# How to use strcpy for pointers?

Tags: c, string, pointers

Why it stops working? Can't we pass the name of the pointer as an argument for strcpy? if I change it to `strcpy(&a,&b);` it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main() {

    char *a;
    a = "aabtyn";

    char *b;
    b =  "mihli";

    strcpy(a,b);

    printf("%s-%s\n",a,b);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it does not work with `strcpy(&a,&b);`

Comment: Although the underlying cause of the duplicate problem is the same, this problem, as seen by the OP, looks different, because writing is wrapped in `strcpy`. I am voting to re-open this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

You declared two pointers to string literals

```
char *a;
a = "aabtyn";

char *b;
b =  "mihli";
```

Then in this statement

```
strcpy(a,b);
```

you are trying to modify the first string literal. So the behaviour of the program is undefined.

As for this statement

```
strcpy(&a,&b);
```

then there is an attempt to copy the value of one pointer to another pointer. This call aslo has undefined behaviour. But if the value of the second pointer is zero-terminated then this call can be equivalent to

```
a = b;
```

So the first pointer just reassigned. Though in any case there is undefined behaviour.

A valid program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "aabtyn";

    char *a = s;

    char *b;
    b =  "mihli";

    strcpy(a,b);

    printf("%s-%s\n",a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can't we pass the name of the pointer as an argument for `strcpy`?

Yes, we can. However, it is also important that the destination pointer points to a writeable memory; in your case, neither `a` nor `b` point to memory that can be written.

> if I change it to `strcpy(&a,&b);` it works.

If it appears to work on your system, it does so by mistake. What you see is undefined behavior. In order for `strcpy` to work you need to do one of the following:

- Allocate `a` in automatic memory by defining it as `char a[] = "aabtyn";`, or
- Allocate `a` in dynamic memory by calling `char *a = malloc(7);` You need seventh byte for null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
char source[80],dest[80];
```

Initialize source, then:

```
strcpy(dest,source);
```

But if you have:

```
char *pd,*ps;
```

Initialize source,and malloc storage for ***pd**, then:

```
strcpy(&pd,&ps);
```

And remember to have **free(pd);** somewhere before **exit(0);**